# Need xpath for the country code

Tags: xml, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Can someone help to find the right xpath for this?

I need to capture the country code, for that i need to identify the element. I tried following xpaths, with no luck.

The linerarlayout at index 1

//[@class='android.widget.LinearLayout' and @index=1]/**.//**[@resource-id='com.whatsapp:id/country_code' and @index=1]

//[@class='android.widget.LinearLayout' and @index=1]/**..//**[@resource-id='com.whatsapp:id/country_code' and @index=1]

//[@class='android.widget.LinearLayout' and @index=1]/**../**[@resource-id='com.whatsapp:id/country_code' and @index=1]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of the XPath you posted is valid. Basically, predicate (expression in `[]` brackets) need to be applied on a context element, for example on a `TextView` :

```
//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id='com.whatsapp:id/country_code']
```

The XPath above will find `<android.widget.TextView>` element, anywhere in the page, where `resource-id` attribute value equals `"com.whatsapp:id/country_code"`. Assuming that `resource-id` attribute is unique, that XPath should be enough to find the target `TextView`.